# Handling Unique Record Exceptions in a Controller

Tags: ruby-on-rails, exception

I have a model called Subscription that has a unique index on the fields [:email, :location]. This means one email address can subscribe per location.

In my model:

```
class Subscription < ActiveRecord::Base
  validates :email, :presence => true, :uniqueness => true, :email_format => true, :uniqueness => {:scope => :location}
end
```

In my create method. I want to handle the the exception `ActiveRecord::RecordNotUnique` differently than a regular error. How would I add that in to this generic create method?

```
  def create
    @subscription = Subscription.new(params[:subscription])
    respond_to do |format|
      if @subscription.save
        format.html { redirect_to(root_url, :notice => 'Subscription was successfully created.') }
      else
        format.html { render :action => 'new' }
      end
    end
  end
```

Answer (score 18, accepted):

I don't think there is a way to have an exception thrown just for a single type of validation failure. Either you can do a `save!` which would raise exceptions for all save errors (including all validation errors) and have them handled separately.

What you can do is handle the exception `ActiveRecord::RecordInvalid` and match the exception message with `Validation failed: Email has already been taken` and then handle it separately. But this also means that you would have to handle other errors too.

Something like,

```
begin
  @subscription.save!
rescue ActiveRecord::RecordInvalid => e
  if e.message == 'Validation failed: Email has already been taken'
    # Do your thing....
  else
    format.html { render :action => 'new' }
  end
end
format.html { redirect_to(root_url, :notice => 'Subscription was successfully created.') }
```

I'm not sure if this is the only solution to this though.

Comment: The `save!` is what I was missing. Both work, however, your solution is more thorough though. I also made a small edit in the rescue line that SO says needs to be peer reviewed.

Comment: should be `rescue ActiveRecord::RecordInvalid, Exception => e`

Comment: Please don't rescue from `Exception`, as that is the superclass of all exceptions in Ruby. You are effectively rescuing *all* exceptions. Just `ActiveRecord::RecordInvalid` will do.

Comment: please note, if your message is translated by i18n... the == won't work

Comment: Actually I use ActiveRecord::RecordNotUnique instead.

Answer (score 10):

You will want to use [`rescue_from`](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveSupport/Rescuable/ClassMethods.html#method-i-rescue_from)

In your controller

```
 rescue_from ActiveRecord::RecordNotUnique, :with => :my_rescue_method

 ....

 protected

 def my_rescue_method
   ...
 end
```

However, wouldn't you want to invalidate your record rather than throwing an exception?

Comment: This is if it is already found in the database. No need to invalidate it, but I'm open to better suggestions. Also, it looks like the error being thrown is actually `ActiveRecord::RecordInvalid Exception: Validation failed: Email has already been taken', not RecordNotUnique.

Comment: As Dex points out, the correct exception is ActiveRecord::RecordInvalid.

Comment: `RecordInvalid` is raised when the same data was present in DB before this current data was being saved. This is rails application-level handling.
`RecordNotUnique` is raised when application assumed that no such record was present in DB and then attempted to save it, but, another request wrote exact same data at the same time thus DB refused to save record from this request. This is DB-level handling of uniqueness.

Answer (score 9):

A couple things I would change about the validation:

1. Do the presence, uniqueness, and format validations in separate validations. (Your uniqueness key in the attributes hash you are passing to "validates" is being overwritten in your validation).  I would make it look more like:

   validates_uniqueness_of :email, :scope => :location

   validates_presence_of :email

   validates_format_of :email, :with => RFC_822   # We use global validation regexes
2. Validations are Application level, one of the reasons you should separate them is because the presence and format validations can be done without touching the database.  The uniqueness validation will touch the database, but won't use the unique index that you setup.  Application level validations don't interact with the database internals they generate SQL and based on the query results make a determination of validity.  You can leave the validates_uniqueness_of but be prepared for race conditions in your application.

Since the validation is application level it will request the row (something like **"SELECT * FROM subscriptions WHERE email = 'email_address' LIMIT 1"**), if a row is returned then the validation fails.  If a row is not returned then it is considered valid.

However, if at the same time someone else signs up with the same email address and they both do not return a row before creating a new one then the 2nd "save" commit will trigger the uniqueness Database index constraint without triggering the validation in the application.  (Since most likely they are running on different application servers or at least different VM's or processes).

**ActiveRecord::RecordInvalid** is raised when the validation fails, not when the unique index constraint on the database is violated.  (There are multiple levels of ActiveRecord Exceptions that can be triggered at different points in the request/response lifecycle)

RecordInvalid is raised at the first level (Application level) whereas **RecordNotUnique** can be raised after the submission is attempted and the database server determines the transaction does not meet the index constraint.  (**ActiveRecord::StatementInvalid** is the parent of the post fetch Exception that will be raised in this instance and you should rescue it if you are actually trying to get the database feedback and not the Application level validation)

If you are in your controller **"rescue_from"** (as outlined by The Who) should work just fine to recover from these different types of errors and it looks like the initial intent was to handle them differently so you can do so with multiple **"rescue_from"** calls.

Comment: Want to add that `ActiveRecord::StatementInvalid` can happen in `save` too. `ActiveModel::RangeError` can also happen. I bet there are more exception classes.

Answer (score 5):

Adding to Chirantans answer, with Rails 5 (or 3/4, with this [Backport](https://github.com/cowbell/active_model-errors_details)) you can also use the new `errors.details`:

```
begin
  @subscription.save!
rescue ActiveRecord::RecordInvalid => e
  e.record.errors.details
  # => {"email":[{"error":"taken","value":"user@example.org"}]}
end
```

Which is very handy for differentiating between the different `RecordInvalid` types and does not require relying on the exceptions error-message.

Note that it includes all errors reported by the validation-process, which makes handling multiple uniqueness-validation-errors much easier.

For example, you can check if all validation-errors for a model-attribute are just uniqueness-errors:

```
exception.record.errors.details.all? do |hash_element|
  error_details = hash_element[1]  
  error_details.all? { |detail| detail[:error] == :taken }
end
```

Answer (score 5):

This gem rescues the constraint failure at the model level and adds a model error (model.errors) so that it behaves like other validation failures. Enjoy! https://github.com/reverbdotcom/rescue-unique-constraint

Comment: This is great. Thank you!