# Rails database uniqueness validation not working

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, validation, ruby-on-rails-4

I am at a total loss with this one. I have a Rails application in which users may create a new vendor for use in the system. This vendor must have a unique name. As such we have a unique index on the database for this field as seen below:

```
create_table "vendors", force: :cascade do |t|
  t.string   "vendor_name", limit: 80, null: false
  t.datetime "updated_at",             null: false
end

add_index "vendors", ["vendor_name"], name: "vendor_name_UNIQUE", unique: true, using: :btree
```

My issue is that for some reason the Rails validation is not working with this, therefore the application is throwing an exception because the database query is failing. The exception is below:

```
ActiveRecord::RecordNotUnique in VendorsController#create

Mysql2::Error: Duplicate entry '3 logiq' for key 'vendor_name_UNIQUE': INSERT INTO `vendors` (`vendor_name`, `updated_at`) VALUES ('3 logiq', '2015-12-03 21:14:12')
```

My Rails validation in the vendor.rb model file is as follows:

```
validates :vendor_name, presence: true, uniqueness: true, length: { minimum: 5, maximum: 80 }
```

I know the validation is being run, because I still receive form errors for the length and presence checks. Unsure what I can do at this point. Have I missed something?

Below is my vendors controller code:

```
def create
  @vendor = Vendor.new(vendor_params)
  @vendor.comments.build(user_comment: comment_params[:new_comment], system_note: 'Created Vendor', user: current_user, user_agent: request.user_agent, resolution: comment_params[:screen_resolution])

  respond_to do |format|
    if @vendor.save
      format.html { redirect_to vendors_path, notice: 'Vendor was successfully created.' }
      format.json { render :show, status: :created, location: @vendor }
    else
      format.html { @new_item = true; render :new }
      format.json { render json: @vendor.errors, status: :unprocessable_entity }
    end
  end
end
```

Vendor form view code:

```
<% if @vendor.errors.any? %>
    <div>
      <div class="alert alert-danger" role="alert" id="error_explanation">
        <h4><strong><%= pluralize(@vendor.errors.count, "error") %></strong> prohibited this vendor from being saved:</h4>

        <ul>
          <% @vendor.errors.full_messages.each do |message| %>
              <li><%= message %></li>
          <% end %>
        </ul>
      </div>
    </div>
<% end %>
```

Comment: Isn't `ActiveRecord::RecordNotUnique in VendorsController#create` ActiveRecord telling you it's not unique? It can check the length and presence without asking the DB but it has to ask the DB for the uniqueness check.

Comment: That's where I understood the `uniqueness: true` of the validation to handle checking the DB, which according to my logs, it is doing. But I never get bounced back for a regular form error. It simply throws the exception.

Comment: Take a look at http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4982371/handling-unique-record-exceptions-in-a-controller

Comment: Also: http://edgeguides.rubyonrails.org/active_record_validations.html#displaying-validation-errors-in-views

Comment: My apologies for not being clear. I do have error views set up, and the other portions of this validation check do work correctly. However, it is specifically the `uniqueness: true` that is as if it is being ignored.

Comment: I would try separating `validates_uniqueness_of  :vendor_name` from the other validations.

Comment: As a a matter of fact, I have another model and controller for user accounts with almost identical code checking uniqueness and it works flawlessly. That is where I am confused.

Comment: Further down in one of those answers to that question I referenced they talk about having code to rescue that validation. Can you add the code that IS working and also the view code?

Comment: @max I just attempted that and received the same exception.

Comment: Please post large amounts of code in the original question using the edit feature. It is almost impossible to read it in comments and other people reading the question don't see it immediately.

Comment: @Beartech My apologies. Posted at bottom of original post.

Comment: Could it be about case sensitivity?

Comment: @HalilÖzgür You are correct! Wow, I assumed that Rails did not care about case sensitivity by default.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The issue was in fact related to case sensitivity. The solution was to add a small bit to the validation line in the vendor model.

The previous validation line:

`validates :vendor_name, presence: true, uniqueness: true, length: { minimum: 5, maximum: 80 }`

Becomes:

`validates :vendor_name, presence: true, uniqueness: { case_sensitive: false }, length: { minimum: 5, maximum: 80 }`

Notice the difference in the `uniqueness` part. Rails does care about case sensitivity by default, therefore my validation was not being ran every single time in my case.

Hope this helps anyone else that comes across this!