# Rails custom validation that limits the number of has_many :through associations allowed?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, forms, validation, activerecord, simple-form

I have a Rails project with a "Product Variant" form. The Product variant model is called `Variant`, and on the `Variant` form users should be able to select one choice for each option available. For instance a T-Shirt might have an "Option" called "Size" with the "Choices" small, medium, or large, and another "Option" called one "Color" with the "Choices" red, green, blue. Thus, the `Variant` created is a unique SKU such as a "T-shirt — Size: Small, Color: Green." Or if it were a product that had 3 options instead of 2, the variant would require 3 choices per option, such as "Guitar Strap - Size: Long, Fabric Color: Red, Leather Color: Brown".

I can't figure out how to write a custom validation that only allows the user to save one choice per option. Each option should only have one choice selected for each variant. Here's an illustration.

[image: need a validation that prevents this]

[image: correct outcome]

Here are my models with the relevant associations...

`models/variant.rb`

```
class Variant < ApplicationRecord    
  has_many :selections
  has_many :choices, through: :selections

  validate :one_choice_per_option

  private
    def one_choice_per_option
      # can't figure out how to do this custom validation here
    end

end
```

`models/choice.rb`

```
class Choice < ApplicationRecord
  has_many :variants, through: :selections

  belongs_to :option
end
```

`models/selection.rb`

```
class Selection < ApplicationRecord
  belongs_to :choice
  belongs_to :variant
end
```

`models/option.rb`

```
class Option < ApplicationRecord
  has_many :choices, dependent: :destroy

  accepts_nested_attributes_for :choices, allow_destroy: true
end
```

The best I've managed to do is get this custom validation working on in `models/variant.rb`

```
def one_choice_per_option
  self.product.options.each do |option|
    if option.choices.count > 1
      errors.add(:choice, 'Error: select one choice for each option')
    end
  end
end
```

But that only allows one `Choice` total through the variant form. What I want to do is allow one choice for each set of options.

I know that this could be done with Javascript in the UI, but this is essential to keeping the database clean and preventing a user error, so I believe it should be a Rails validation at the model level.

What is a "Railsy" way to do this type of custom validation? Should I be trying to do a custom validation on the `Selection` model? If so, how?

---

## UPDATE

Based on the discussion in the comments. It seems that I need to do some combination of [Active Record querying](https://guides.rubyonrails.org/active_record_querying.html) to make this work. @sevensidedmarble's "EDIT 2" below is closer but that is giving me this error: `Type Error compared with non class/module`

If I save the wrong behavior to the database and then call `Variant.last.choices` in the console it feels like I'm getting closer:

[image: illustrating the form behavior I need to prevent with a validation]

[image: showing the console response]

So essentially, what I need to do is not allow the `Variant` form to save if there is more than one `Selection` with the same `option_id`. A selection shouldn't save unless the `option_id` is unique to the associated `Variant`.

Something like this is what I'm trying to do:

```
validate :selections_must_have_unique_option

  private

    def selections_must_have_unique_option
      unless self.choices.distinct(:option_id)
        errors.add(:options, 'can only have one choice per option')
      end
    end
```

But that code doesn't work. It just saves the form as if the validation weren't there.

Comment: your first answer itself seems okay to me. I am just not sure about the relationships here. Do you have a variant-belongs_to-product, product-has_many-options relationship defined? If not, could you please tell us the relationship hierarchy here, as I am getting confused in between on 'product' model aspect.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's analogous to a uniqueness constraint, but Rails's built-in [`validates_uniqueness_of`](https://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveRecord/Validations/ClassMethods.html#method-i-validates_uniqueness_of) can't handle this: the validation required is on each Selection object, but it's by option, and the `selections` table doesn't *have* an `option_id` column to constrain.

You can't easily do it in the database, either, because unique indexes don't cross table boundaries.

I suggest you have each `Selection` object look for a conflicting sibling, and use an [absence validation](https://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveModel/Validations/HelperMethods.html#method-i-validates_absence_of) on the result.  Something like this:

```
class Variant < ApplicationRecord    
  has_many :selections
  has_many :choices, through: :selections
end

class Selection < ApplicationRecord
  belongs_to :choice
  belongs_to :variant

  validates_absence_of :conflicting_selection

  protected
    def option
      choice.option
    end

    def conflicting_selection
      variant.selections.excluding(self).detect { |other| option == other.option }
    end
end
```

Eagle eyes will notice that I've used array methods rather than ActiveRecord queries.  This isn't a cheesy gimmick to avoid a database round-trip; it ensures that the validation works correctly on unsaved selections as well as those persisted, which might be essential for form processing.  That `Selection#option` method, which I'd normally want to write as `has_one :option, through: :choice`, is in a similar vein.

Sample gist with unit tests [here](https://gist.github.com/inopinatus/ee6dcc3e0c5cc1ab4d8a6cdeb395175d) if you need it.

Comment: Wow! Thank you so much for such a thorough answer. That definitely worked. What is the idiomatically "Rails" way to handle this type of exception in the `VariantsController` and `views/variants/_edit`? I tried adding something like `If ActiveRecord::RecordInvalid` to my `variants#update` action but that did not work.  Because this is an error on the `Selection` model and not the `Variant` form, how should those errors work with the `Variant` form?

Comment: Also, instead of using this `validates_absence_of` would you recommend, should I instead add a `has_one :option, through: :choice` association to my `Selection` model?

Comment: Hopefully you will never see an `ActiveRecord::RecordInvalid` exception in a view! That would suggest a view had attempted a database write. Idiomatically speaking, exceptions should not be used for flow control: the standard way is to just let `#save` or `#update` return a falsy response. So in your update action, you write `if @variant.update(secure_params); ...; else;` and the else block handles the error case. That's basically as described in the standard scaffolding and in the [Getting Started guide](https://guides.rubyonrails.org/getting_started.html#updating-articles).

Comment: For the error display, I'd use a fields_for [nested form](https://guides.rubyonrails.org/form_helpers.html#nested-forms) on the selections. The standard Rails form builder will give each conflicted selection a `field_with_errors` wrapper div you can use for styling.

Comment: A `has_one` association does not replace the absence validation. It'd replace the `#option` method. However in this case it is contra-indicated.

Comment: Right, it wasn't the view that I was doing that in. If I add your validation on the `Selection` model and then test it in the browser, I get this error from rails https://imgur.com/a/FFtjJvf. So I was trying to do something like this in my `VariantsController` in the update action: https://gist.github.com/leemcalilly/51be9f15f1c1370f101959c6dbd25396 That didn't work though. Would something like this be correct: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4982371/handling-unique-record-exceptions-in-a-controller?answertab=active#tab-top ??

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/199754/discussion-between-inopinatus-and-lee-mcalilly).

Answer (score 1):

Something like this should work:

```rb
def one_choice_per_option
      errors.add(:choice, "can't be more then one per selection") if selections.any { |selection| selection.choices.count > 1 }
end
```

Alternatively, I suspect you could also just have selections `has_one :choice` and then your life might be simpler.

---

EDIT:

as requested in comments, here's an update I think will do exactly as requested:

```rb
def one_choice_per_option
      errors.add(:choice, "can't be more then one per selection") if selections.joins(:choice).where(selections: :choice).count > 3
end
```

I think this will get what you want. If not we just need to mess with the `joins` and `where` part slightly, let me know.

EDIT 2:

---

Ok, after discussion again I'm a little more clear on what's requested. Sorry for it taking a while, it's hard to understand the schema without seeing it in front of you in your own app.

Here's what I *think* would work for what specified. I wrote it here from the context of `Product` but it would work with a little change on `Option` too.

```rb
def one_choice_per_option
  errors.add(:options, "can't be more then one per selection") if (options.joins(:choices).group("options.id").having("COUNT(1) > 1") > 1)
end
```

I think that should work, if not it's really close to what you need. This SQL is the basic idea. Sometimes it can help to call `.to_sql` on these queries to see exactly what activerecords pumping out.

---

EDIT 3:

I was thinking about your original code on `Variant`, and came up with this as well:

```rb
class Variant < ApplicationRecord
  has_many :selections
  has_many :choices, through: :selections

  validate :one_choice_per_option

  private
  def one_choice_per_option
    if (choices.joins(:option).group("options.id").having("COUNT(1) > 1") > 1)
      errors.add(:choices, "can't be more then one per selection") 
    end
  end
end
```

Comment: Thanks! I was able to get close with `errors.add(:choice, "can't be more then one per selection") if self.selections.any? { |selection| selection.choices.count > 1 }` but that is still giving me an `undefined method 'choices'` error. That is a similar error to others I've gotten when trying to write this validation. Can the selection model `has_one :choice` if I'm using it as the join model for a `Variant` to `have_many :choices, through: :selection`?

Comment: I believe you could do that too. Also you could change the belongs_to to has_many to make the code I posted work, but then you would need to move the foreign key if that makes sense.

Comment: trying to add `has_one :choice` to the `selection` model while also using it as the join table did not work for me. I'm not understanding where you're suggesting "change the belongs_to to has_many". Do you mean change the `Selection` model to "has_one" choice? I need it to join the choice to the variant, so how would that work?

Comment: Give me a moment, I'm going to look through your schema again and see if there's a better way. I think we could do it with the current schema with a slightly different validation. I think we can do it with a joins clause and where clause.

Comment: Ok I've tweaked it for you, I think this approach will work without schema changes. Let me know if not, but I think this is the approach I'd take.

Comment: Really appreciate the help! Your new code gives me an error `comparison of Symbol with 3 failed`. Even if that did work, that's not really the intended behavior. Not all Selections will have 3 options. A T-shirt might have 2 options with any number of choices (say 5 colors for the "color" option and 4 size for the "size" option). But another type of product might only have 2 choices from one option. So how would you express with the `where` method that each select should have no more than one "choice" saved while the variant itself still has_many choices? (e.g. a "small," "red" t-shirt)

Comment: My bad, there's a typo I can fix in it.

Comment: And gotcha I think I see what you mean... Let me think about that for a moment...

Comment: Again, thanks so much. Dropping down into the console and playing with the queries is helping point me in the right direction. I'm still stuck tho. Updated my question with additional screenshots and notes. Your "EDIT 2" code gives me this error: `Type Error compared with non class/module`. I think what I really need to do is not allow a selection pass through my variant form unless it the selection object has a unique `option_id`. Added a console screenshot to illustrate, but still struggling with how to do that.

Comment: Does selection have an `option_id` column? I thought it was just a join table with only choice_id and variant_id

Comment: Also I edited it again, I think that error you mentioned was just the interpreter needing some parens there. Does that edit make that error not happen?

Comment: There's no `option_id` on `Selection`. As in my console log above, if you run `Variants.last.choices` it returns the related `option_id` because my `Choice` model `belongs_to :option`. So I thought I might be able to access it that way and validate that the `option_id` must be unique to pass thru the `Selection` and save the `Variant`. The missing parens was a problem, but if I run your `Edit 2` I get an error that says `undefined local variable or method `options' `. Do I need to add an extra association for `Option`? In my Variant form view this works: `@variant.product.options.each do`...

Comment: Also, because `@variant.product.options` worked in my view, I figured this edit to your code might work `errors.add(:options, "can't be more then one per selection") if (product.options.joins(:choices).group("options.id").having("COUNT(1) > 1") > 1)` but that returns a `TypeError` `compared with non class/module`.

Comment: Might be best to just wrap it in an actual if on three lines like:
if (product.options.joins(:choices).group("options.id").having("COUNT(1) > 1") > 1)
   errors.add(:options, "can't be more then one per selection") 
end

Comment: Sorry that doesn't line wrap well in the comments but you know what I mean?

Comment: Added another EDIT 3 there, based on putting the validation on `Variant`, which is I think what you intended in the beginning. Does that join correctly?

Comment: That gives an `undefined method `joins` error. I tried it with just `join` and it's the same error.

Comment: I truly appreciate your trying to help me figure this out. Still getting the same `undefined method `joins'` error. I've been playing around with it, but not sure I understand what you're trying to do.

Comment: See update above, I was thinking in terms of scopes for some reason where you don't have to put the relationship before the join. Sorry I couldn't help you out more :/

Comment: For what it's worth I think my solution in edit 3 is a much better way of doing it. You can absolutely get at this info without using detect, which would make the validation slower. Mine should just use ActiveRecord.

Comment: I can definitely see how it's a good idea to only touch ActiveRecord, but I'm still not able to get your suggestion working and I'm not sure I quite understand it. The current version is giving me this error: `TypeError in VariantsController#update` `compared with non class/module` Truly appreciate your help this this though.

Comment: This means something in my validation there is throwing an error, and then trying to compare it... It's hard to see for me what it is without taking that line in rails console and running it prefixed by the model